# Is there a way to see how far you are in an advancement in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and some of my friends are taking on a challenge to get all of the advancements you can get in minecraft, and while I was trying to get the "A Balanced Diet" advancement I realized that you cannot see which foods you have eaten and which ones you still need to eat. After looking at some of the other advancements (such as "Two by Two" and "Discover Every Biome".)It would be very helpful to know how much of the advancement I have done, and how much I still need to do.

Is there a way to do this? I am hoping that if you press a button on your keyboard or or something similar to show it. Sadly, so far I am at a dead end.

Comment: I doubt it . I've researched a lot of sites and noone has said its possible anywhere.

Comment: I may be miss-remembering, but aren't there some advancements where you CAN see your progress? Would it then be possible to edit all the advancements in a datapack folder so it would show you your progress? I wouldn't know how, though, but if it were possible I'm sure someone else would answer.

Comment: General tip, not just for this site: Please Do Not Type Like This, it's super annoying and makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't even appear in `/data get entity @s` and I also can't find it anywhere in the save data.

Comment: I think the best way would be to write down what you've done so far somewhere.

Comment: I made a datapack that adds the individual triggers as child advancements. Once I uploaded it somewhere, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: So, I tried putting all the steps of each advancement into individual child advancements. Unfortunately, upon loading the world, Minecraft just shuts down. No Forge message, no crash report, no nothing. It's simply gone. I think it simply can't handle that many advancements on the same level. Either that, or Brine is pissed when you overwrite its hardcodedly triggered one (which I tried to do in the same datapack).

Answer (score 15):

It is important to understand how Advancements work internally before trying to track your progress on different Advancements.

##Where are Advancements stored?

Advancements are stored in the world data folder as a JSON file. The path to reach the file that stores your progress is as follows.

- Windows: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\<world>\advancements`
- macOS: `/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/<world>/advancements`
- Linux: `/home/<user>/.minecraft/saves/<world>/advancements`

Upon reaching the folder, a JSON file with your UUID can be found. In my case, the file name is `1f2481d2-9e43-4417-b103-667abb948bfd.json`. You can open the file using your favourite text editor.

##How are Advancements tracked?

For every action performed in Minecraft, a certain trigger is "activated". The game then records the actions you have performed by updating info stored in the Advancements JSON file mentioned above.

For instance, on initial world creation, the Advancement file is blank.

Then, I join the world. Immediately on join, the following is written into the file:

```
{
  "minecraft:adventure/adventuring_time": {
    "criteria": {
      "minecraft:jungle": "2019-01-21 17:27:40 +0800"
    },
    "done": false
  }
}
```

It is easy to understand the tree of text as below:

> `minecraft:adventure/adventuring_time` is the internal name that the game uses to identify different Advancements.

> `criteria` denotes what objectives needs to be completed in order to finish an Advancement. *Only objectives that have already been met will be shown.* This can be seen later in this answer. On a new criterion completion, the details are immediately written into the file. In my case, I spawned in the Jungle biome for the first time (its internal name is `minecraft:jungle`) at the time 2019/01/21 17:27:40 GMT+8 (which is stored as `2019-01-21 17:27:40 +0800`).

> `done` denotes whether the entire Advancement has been finished. It has a value of `false` by default, meaning the Advancement has not yet been finished. When all criteria has been completed, the value becomes `true` and a toast that congratulates the player on completing an Advancement is correspondingly shown on the game screen.

After joining the game, I randomly walked around and ventured into another biome. The file is immediately updated to the following:

```
{
  "minecraft:adventure/adventuring_time": {
    "criteria": {
      "minecraft:jungle": "2019-01-21 17:27:40 +0800",
      "minecraft:jungle_hills": "2019-01-21 17:32:28 +0800"
    },
    "done": false
  }
}
```

which reflects that I have entered the Jungle Hills biome for the first time at 5:32pm.

As seen from above, the file is constantly edited to keep the game up to date on your progress. So, we can always obtain the most updated information on Advancement progress through this file.

##So how do I know the detailed progress of each Advancement?

###Give me a tl;dr!
You have to cross-reference the Advancements JSON file with the Advancements page on the Minecraft wiki.

###So how should I do that?
Let's say we want to track the Monsters Hunted Advancement. This Advancement requires a player to kill one of every hostile monster.

1. Visit the Advancements page on the Minecraft wiki (linked below). Navigate to the Monsters Hunted Advancement section in the list of Advancements.
2. Open the Advancements JSON file. Use the search function to quickly find the section `minecraft:adventure/kill_all_mobs`.
3. Check the `criteria` section and see the list of *completed* criteria. Remember what criteria you have completed. If needed, jot them down on a blank document or a piece of paper.
4. Now look at the Advancements page on the Minecraft wiki. The actual requirements state that you have to

> Kill each of *these 24 mobs*. In 1.14,‌[upcoming] also kill each of *these 2 mobs*. Other mobs may be killed, but are ignored for the advancement.
> 5. So, hover your mouse over "these 24 mobs". Check if your list of completed criteria contains each mob. If not, write the missing criterion down.
> 6. When you have finished checking the 24 or 26 mobs, you should now hold a list of criteria that you have yet to complete. Congratulations! You now know what mobs you should focus on killing.
> 7. For extra accuracy, count if the number of items on your list of incomplete criteria matches the number shown in the Advancements GUI in-game.

###I can't find a certain Advancement ID!

If you are unable to find the Advancement ID in the file, that means you either made a typo, or have made no progress on that Advancement at all.

###Are there less obnoxious ways?

At current stage, no.

The main issue is that the criteria that you have never met before is not stored in the file. There is no way to check detailed progress grouped by each Advancement in-game.

Do note that Fabian's answer provides an in-game way to manually check if a very specific criterion is met. It may be easier when only a few criteria are left and you have a vague idea on what you have not yet done. However, this method only works when commands are enabled.

##Links

For a list of Advancements and their internal IDs, criteria for specific Advancements, the general structure of the Advancements JSON file and more, visit the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancements).

Comment: Oh, I totally overlooked that! For some reason I thought that the folder `saves/<world>/advancements` contained advancement files from data packs. But of course they are in `saves/<world>/datapacks/<pack>/data/<namespace>/advancements`. In general a great answer, covers everything that one might want to know. You could also get the list of advancement criteria from that version's jar file, but since the location in there or different conditions might change, I think it's better to reference the wiki instead, as you did.

Comment: I think I'll provide a function at some point that outputs which criteria are met and which ones aren't. It can all be automated without changing anything and without triggering "advancement got" popups. But making a really good solution for it requires time, which I don't have that much of currently.

Comment: I did not know that there are in-game ways to check for internal save data and design functions based on the check results. In general how can that be accomplished?

Comment: I meant my answer. You can automate that by getting the result with `execute store success`. And yes, you can access a lot of internals with commands, for example everything in the NBT data of entities.

Answer (score 0):

## This answer works, but there are two much better ones, one by me. [Link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/345363/171580) and [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/346124/171580).

---

I wasn't able to find where this is stored, otherwise you could just look it up there with an NBT editor.

The best I was able to find is running `/advancement (grant|revoke) @s only <advancement> <criterion>` and then the opposite again, if necessary. The feedback message will tell you whether you had that criterion already. Based on that, you can undo that command again.

Answer (score 0):

I totally missed this in the release notes, but there's actually a target selector argument "`advancements`"! It works like this:

```
@a[advancements={story/form_obsidian=false,story/shiny_gear={diamond_helmet=true}}]
```

This selects every player who has not gotten the "ice bucket challenge" advancement in the "Minecraft tab", but have worn a diamond helmet, therefore completing that part of the "cover me with diamonds" advancement.

You can use this to check for all criteria individually. Sadly they are not documented in the wiki, so you'll have to get them out of the version's .jar file in `.minecraft/versions/<version>` (not the path set in the launcher, the one chosen when installing Minecraft, if you had the option, otherwise the default). Inside that .jar file there's the path `data/minecraft/advancements` with sub-folders for all the advancements, containing the advancements in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small Python program which returns the missing biomes, foods, mobs, etc. Currently only tested for the 1.16_20w14. This Program uses the file described in this answer above.

https://github.com/lujobi/minecraft-advancment-progress

Comment: Welcome to the site Luzian! While this certainly sounds helpful,  I'm afraid we don't allow answers which are really just a link to off to another resource or application. Could you please edit your answer to include details on how users can download and install your program, along with how to use it? I'd also suggest including details on the minimum version of Python supported.

Answer (score -2):

Just hover over the advancement...
It works for me.
So simple!

Comment: That only shows you the progress in numbers, like "3/42", not what you already have.